# How to implement a new row_count method in Wordpress?

Tags: wp-query, database, mysql

### Overview

By far, Wordpress, Implements pagination by means of [`SQL_CALC_ROWS_FOUND`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/aaf99e691391cfceb004d848450dbbf3344b1bee/wp-includes/class-wp-site-query.php). But my benchmark have shown that this implementation is **1.1 Million % slower than my queries without it**. So I am thinking of replacing it and implement a faster rows_counting method.  The problem is, how do we integrate that in Wordpress?

### Approach to Solution

I found a [blog post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) that could be a solution. Its an old post however that same issue is still standing as it is today. The post benchmarks `SQL_CALC_ROWS_FOUND` vs. `Ordinary SQL + Count`, and it was found out that ordinary query (without `sql_calc_rows_fount`) to get your requests followed by `COUNT` to determine the number of results was magnitude times faster than the existing implementation

We can disable, the `SQL_CALC_ROWS_FOUND` by:

```
query_posts('no_found_rows=true&cat=1&numberposts=1');
```

as indicated in [this blog](https://flavio.tordini.org/speed-up-wordpress-get_posts-and-query_posts-functions), so when Wordpress runs its usual queries we get the same results as usual, but without paginations! All results were there but no page numbers! Fast but partially useful, since pagination depends on the calculated results found, but we just disabled that calculations. We can get that by Implementing `SELECT Count`, however, how do we pass the results to wordpress so it can do the Paginations?

### Server

Apache 2.4 (fpm), php7, mysql5.7, MyIsam, 8 Core Intel Xeon, 24Gb Ram, SSD.

Comment: Very interesting question, would love to see some solution for this. Nothing that comes to my mind now sadly. Maybe using previous pre_get_posts filter somehow?

Comment: .nobody in wordpress cared to speeding it up?